# Is this soggy soil next to the garage's downspout normal?

Tags: gutters, pest, downspout

[image]

I noticed the soil next to the downspout in the garage is always wet, never dries. Is there an issue that would explain that? Or is it normal given the proximity? Could the irrigation line have puncture pushing the water up all the day, and making the soil in that area soggy?

We spotted cockroaches in the garage and I wonder if that wet soil has become a place for them to nest under.

Thank you!

Comment: So where is the water going? Where does that black pipe end? The water should be carried away from the building, not dumped into the soil right next to it.

Comment: Depends...is that corrugated pipe perforated?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. It seems to me that there is a leak.

Comment: Yeah, that's what they make the flexible thing for; to get it to go *away*.... that you have going into the ground. And your question is what? ;p - IDK about nests but it sure makes it habitable to *all* forms of life.

Comment: My question is if the pipe is perforated based on how wet it is next to it. That area just won't dry at all.